# How to Ignore API call with invalid json body in WSO2 API manager

Tags: json, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I use wso2 API manager for publishing some of my APIs. But my issue is if someone send a API request with invalid json body, is it able to ignore that API call and give some error message to the requested person without sending that invalid json body to the back end.
API manager version : 1.7

- This is the incorrect json request (try to send without value for "moduleCode")

  ```
  {
  "event": {
      "portalType": "dfd",
      "moduleCode": ,
      "role": "3",
      "roleCode": "dfdf",
      "languageID": "gd",
      "password": "dfdfgd",
      "phoneNumber": "2332323",

      "resourceCode": [
          "8045005"
      ]


  }}
  ```

Could it possible to restrict user by value of role in the above json ?
How to achieve this with API Manager 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thre aren't any predefined way to achieve this requirement. But, You can customize WSO2 API Manager to cater this requirement.

You can write a custom handler which will validate the request body and return response if the request has some error rather sending to backend. You can check [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Writing+Custom+Handlers) on how to write a custom handler for API Manager 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Better have that facility with APIM.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this article on ["How to validate JSON request payload in API Manager"](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-validate-json-request-pay-load_8.html). This is exactly address your use case and only thing you need to do is add XSD to match with your request. In API Manager if you need to validate request or pre process message its always recommend to use mediation extensions available with the product.

Comment: not practical in my case. I dont need to validate in that level. I just want to validate whether the request body is valid or not

Comment: In your question you mentioned that "try to send without value for "moduleCode". If you want validate that kind of data within payload our(WSO2) recommendation is to use mediation extension. If need multiple assert then you can do that as well. We usually recommend class mediators when you need to do certain operation in multiple APIs(apply to all apis using velocity template) and you cannot do that operation with mediation extensions.

Answer (score 0):

In coming request will be transform to SOAP format by message builder[1].This message builder will be chosen based on the content type of incoming message.You can write your own message builder for application/json and validate the input. e.g [2]

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters
[2]https://github.com/anuruddhal/WSO2-ESB-Custom-Message-Builder/tree/master/CustomBuilder